# Binding nonlocal address on NetBSD

Tags: networking, ip, netbsd

*This is not a programming question, but a question about NetBSD.*

Linux, FreeBSD and OpenBSD have mutually exclusive but similar interfaces to allow binding the local end of a connection to an address that is not present on any local interface. E.g. make a connection **from** 8.8.8.8. I've been poking around without success in NetBSD to see if there is something to the same effect there. Is there?

Here's (my) sample code, for reference:

https://github.com/UlricE/pen/blob/master/server.c

Function spoof_bind, line ~250.

Greatly simplified examples to illustrate the concept:

Linux:

```
setsockopt(upfd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &one, sizeof one);
bind(upfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);
```

FreeBSD:

```
setsockopt(upfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_BINDANY, &one, sizeof one);
bind(upfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);
```

OpenBSD:

```
setsockopt(upfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDANY, &one, sizeof one);
bind(upfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);
```

Again, this is not a programming question but a question whether such an interface exists on NetBSD.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A client connects to a load balancing proxy which connects to a backend server. The objective is to allow the server to see a connection as coming from the client's IP address.

Comment: http://morestuff.siag.nu/2015/05/29/transparent-reverse-proxy/ for more details.

Comment: Can you add ammendments to the question, and make it a bit clearer. What you say fills my head with ideas, but still I am not certain about what you are trying to do. Do not expect us to read a manual to allow us to understand your question, just because you can not be bothered to tell us clearly what you are trying, do not assume that we know.

Comment: I have added a few examples. This is something you either know or not; if you don't, you are not expected to answer.

Comment: Looks like a port forwarder, but done in kernel routing tables, such that receiving application sees the original address of the connecting device (not the address of the port forwarder).

Comment: Did you bother to check the (NetBSD) source?  I.e. really and truly read everything related to setsockopt() and what it calls?