# FreeBSD alternative for ip route add local

Tags: networking, freebsd, route

On Linux, I can run `ip route add local` i order to add a large amout (e.g. a complete /64 subet) to an interface ([sf#209203](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface)), and using `IP_BINDANY` I can listen to any IP address on FreeBSD ([#207610](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207610/binding-nonlocal-address-on-netbsd)).

But how can I combine these two?  I want to bind to arbitrary addresses within a /64 subnet on FreeBSD.

Comment: This is a follow on from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344599/ .

Comment: They are very closely related, but actually different questions. 344599 is about functionality offered by Kernel >= 4.3 where any socket (without options) can bind to any address. This is to set up routing so that such sockets can actually be used.